# Is it true that $H^{q}\left(X, \mathcal{O}_{X}(d)\right)=(H^{q}\left(X, \mathcal{O}_{X}(d)\right))_0=H^{q}\left(X, (\mathcal{O}_{X}(d))_0\right)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Like in
[image]

The LHS should be a graded module, and the RHS seems that it has taken the $0$-th degree of the result.

Comment: 1. The image in your post is a screenshot of [Stacks 01XT](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01XT) and should be referenced as such. 2. Why do you think the LHS should be a graded module? What grading do you think it should have?

Comment: What is graded is $\oplus_d H^0(\Bbb P^n, \mathcal O(d))$.